# How to alter database/table schema on WP8

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, schema, datacontext

I am developing an WP8 application that uses a database to store its data.
Now i need to replace a column or at least remove a column and add another one instead.

[DatabaseSchemaUpdater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.data.linq.databaseschemaupdater%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is not helping here as it only allows to add columns.
Is there a best practice or an "bullet proof" way to achieve that?

I thought about opening the old database and copy its content to the a new database but then i need to keep track of different schemas and models, because i can only read from a table if i have model class that matches the schema of it.

EDIT:
Ok, i found the answer here: [Unused columns, tables, and databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394018%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_UnusedColumnsTablesandDatabases)